# Swift 3: How to scroll from offset to another offset in UICollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, offset

I want to scroll **from** offset **to** another offset like this:

```
self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = 10  
self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = 22
self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = 15
.
.
.
```

But every time try this code,*UICollectionView* scroll to this **X offset** but start from **zero**. I wanna start from privious x offset not start from zero offset.

Comment: `self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + 22`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: or you can use collectionView.scrollRectToVisible

Comment: Destination offset works correctly but start scrolling from zero. @Rikh